# What is wrong with my mysql delete statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, sql-delete

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with me sql statement? I want it to delete all the table rows that the time interval is more than 1 minute. My sql statement does not show any errors but it wont delete any of the rows.

By the way I'm using the codeigniter framework.

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now());
$query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM table WHERE 'date/time' < ('$new_date' - INTERVAL 1 minute)");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using single quotes around your column identifier instead of ticks

```
$query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM table WHERE `date/time` < ('$new_date' - INTERVAL 1 minute)");
```

Also, `$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now());` should just be `$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` as PHP does *not* have a function called `now()`. Or, even better, just use MySQL's built in date functions:

```
$query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM table WHERE `date/time` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 minute)");
```

FYI, it is not common practice to use `/` in column identifiers.

Comment: Look at the characters surrounding `date/time`. They are `\`` and not `'`.

Comment: I see... Thanks.. So should i use _ instead of / ?

Comment: That would be more "standard"

Comment: @John, you could also opt for a more descriptive name that talks about what data the column stores: `CreateDate`,  `LastModifiedDate`, `TrialExpirationDate`; You'll be thanked when someone has to troubleshoot an issue at 3am.